# Foreign key relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to add an object created from Entity Data Model classes. I have a table called Users, which has turned into a User EDM class. And I also have a table Pages, which has become a Page EDM class. These tables have a foreign key relationship, so that each page is associated with many users. Now I want to be able to add a page, but I can't get how to do it. I get a nullreference exception on Users below. I'm still rather confused by all this, so I'm sure it's a simple error, but I just can't see how to do it.

Also, by the way, the compiler requires that I set PageID in the object initializer, even though this field is set to be an automatic id in the table. Am I doing it right just setting it to 0, expecting it to be updated automatically in the table when saved, or how should I do that?

Any help appreciated!

The method in question:

```
private Page GetPage(User currentUser)
{
   string url = _request.ServerVariables["url"].ToLower();
   var userPages = from p in _context.PageSet
                     where p.Users.UserID == currentUser.UserID
                     select p;
   var existingPage = userPages.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Url == url);

   if (existingPage != null)
      return existingPage;

   Page page = new Page()
                   {
                      Count = 0,
                      Url = _request.ServerVariables["url"].ToLower(),
                      PageID = 0, //Only initial value, changed later?
                   };

   _context.AddToPageSet(page);
   page.Users.UserID = currentUser.UserID; //Here's the problem...
   return page;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
page.Users = _context.Users.First(u => u.UserId == currentUser.UserID);
```

Regarding this:

> Also, by the way, the compiler requires that I set PageID in the object initializer

That should not be true. What is the exact error message? Also, what is the type of the ID?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work... First, your expression tries to assign a User object to an int (UserID). So I changed to             page.Users.UserID = _context.UserSet.First(u => u.UserID == currentUser.UserID).UserID; But that doesn't work either. Still nullreference on the Users part of page.Users.UserID. I'm trying to add a new page row, and then set the foreign key UserID on that new page to the current User objects UserID (primary key). Am I missing something here? Obviously the Users collection of the new page is empty, but what do I need to do to add it then?

Comment: Sorry; copy/paste error. Fixed. Based on your code above, `Users` looks like a single `User`, not a collection.

Comment: You're right, it's not a collection. But why would it be called Users then...? But this works! I investigated a little further though, and e.g. here it's recommended not to do it this way: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/18/entity-framework-relations-and-entitykey/ (due to overhead apparently). But the alternative code is really over-complicated, so I'd rather go with your suggestion. Any take on this? (I'm using EF 3.5 btw, is 4.0 different in this respect?). Thanks for your help!

Comment: About the Users property, apparently it is a "Navigation property", looking  in the Entity model designer. They're a bit confusing... Besides my question above, my User EDM class also got 3 navigation properties - "Pages", "Users1", and "Users2", while the Page EDM class only got the one "Users" navigation property. What is going on with these?

Comment: It's called `Users` because EF 1 doesn't automatically (de)pluralize. EF 4 does. Regarding `Users1`, etc, look at mapping details in the EF desinger; it should tell you what they represent.